# Executing several python files on the same interactive prompt on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I'm transitioning from Spyder to VS Code, and I'm having an issue executing ad-hoc code on an interactive session. I first save this to a tmp1.py and run the selection on an interactive window:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4],
                   'b': [1,1,2,3]})
```

Then on tmp2.py I just write and run:

```
print(df)
```

It opens a **new** interactive window and complains `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`. How can I configure it to run on the currently active window / session? Note that I'm not using a Jupyter notebook but IPython.

At some point I'll want to run code in parallel on several terminals, but at first I'd like to get this simple set-up working.

Comment: Put the print function in the same file as where you define `df`. That's how Python programs work: they don't magically use variables from other files.

Comment: If you're really using IPython, you can `%run tmp1.py`, then `%run -i tmp2.py` on the next prompt, so that `tmp2.py` gets its variables from the current namespace. But that doesn't really makes sense: why are tmp1.py and tmp2.py separate, instead of just being one logical Python script?

Comment: python does not work parallel because it has the GIL

Comment: @rioV8 You can use multiprocessing, or just run the scripts in parallel; perhaps the latter is what the OP intends to do. But it's not relevant to the question here anyway.

Comment: On Spyder IPython session I can just run arbitary ad-hoc code, it isn't linked to any specific file. Actually you can also evaluate expressions from un-saved files as well, it is basically same as copy-pasting the code to IPython and getting the result there. It doesn't matter where the python code snippet originates from. I'd rather not try to explain why on this example the print function is in an other file, it could be just an other ad-hoc script which I haven't bothered to "functionalize" to be imported from file tmp2 to tmp1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason my "Jupyter > Interactive Window: Creation Mode" setting was "**perfile**", although "**multiple**" is supposed to be the default. After changing it to "multiple" everything works logically. I can also open sevaral interactive windows, and the selected code gets evaluated in the active one.

Answer (score 2):

Just run them in the same interactive window:

[image]

Comment: In my VS Code that command opens two IPythons: "interactive - tmp1.py" and "interactive - tmp2.py". This is precisely my problem, I'd like to run them in the same one :D

Comment: Can you provide your personal settings and installed extensions?

Comment: Ah, for some reason my "Jupyter > Interactive Window: Creation Mode" was "perfile", although "multiple" is supposed to be the default. I'm not sure whether to answer my own question, or if you edit your answer to include this info then I can accept it as correct :)

Comment: You can of course answer your own question. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.  Just a reminder :)